# .htaccess/.htpasswd not working on web host

Tags: .htaccess

I have my website setup on a web host. My .htaccess and .htpasswd files are not working. The alert pops up but it keeps asking for the username and password even though I input the correct credentials.

The directory of these files is:
`/home8/afmaclub/public_html/Members/.htaccess` 
`/home8/afmaclub/public_html/Members/.htpasswd`

The code for the .htaccess and .htpasswd is below:
**.htaccess**

```
AuthName "Member\'s Area"
AuthUserFile /home/afmaclub/public_html/Members/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

**.htpasswd**

```
Username:Encrypted Password
```

Comment: how did you generate the .htpasswd file?

Comment: I used htaccesstools.com - [link](http://htaccesstools.com)

Comment: might be you have incorrect path of `.htpasswd`?

Comment: I'm fairly sure I have the correct path for .htpasswd @Ben

Comment: you have different paths given from you question, `/home/...` compares to `/home8/...`, might be the cause?